# I have Ubuntu installed on my laptop in dual mode which was working fine but now it's freezed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, freeze

While selecting the Ubuntu mode in the dual system, the screen gets freezed and after opening the recovery mode there is not a single signal of opening the Ubuntu OS. So please suggest some solutions to make my system work asap.

[image: 1]

As in the image, when the system gets started, the following window appears on the screen and stays for hours.

Comment: Are you getting grub menu? or is it stopping before grub menu? And even recovery boot, second line in grub menu does not boot to terminal/command line? What brand/model system? What video card/chip? What updates were just done? Something in Windows changing UEFI to default settings, so you have to redo changes you made for Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, getting the grub menu. No updates were performed.

Comment: You do not always see Windows updates. Default is just to do them in background. Can you not boot recovery mode?

Comment: I have tried booting the recovery mode but it's not working. After booting, only the black screen appears.

Comment: With recovery mode, you should get each line of the boot process on screen that is also stored in the log files. What brand/model system? What video card/chip? Did you modify fstab as error in fstab can stop boot. Post this in question. `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,fstype,uuid,partuuid | egrep -v "^loop"`